# VBA Copy Entire Row to New Sheet Based on Value in Range

Tags: excel, vba

Despite reading several threads searching for answers to similar problems I have been unable to debug my code on its own.

I am trying to write a macro that will search all cells between AE and BF for the term "Aeronautics Engineers" and then copy all rows that contain that term to a new sheet. The entire sheet has a total of 99289.

I have tried using the following code without any luck:

```
Sub MoveAero()
Dim strArray As Variant
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim NoRows As Long
Dim DestNoRows As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Integer
Dim rngCells As Range
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim Found As Boolean

strArray = Array("Aeronautic")

Set wsSource = ActiveSheet

NoRows = wsSource.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
DestNoRows = 1
Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

For I = 1 To NoRows

    Set rngCells = wsSource.Range("AE" & I & ":BF" & I)
    Found = False
    For J = 0 To UBound(strArray)
        Found = Found Or Not (rngCells.Find(strArray(J)) Is Nothing)
    Next J

    If Found Then
        rngCells.EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Range("A" & DestNoRows)

        DestNoRows = DestNoRows + 1
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Store the search string to a variable, not array.

Comment: Consider describing what you mean by "Without any luck". Are there errors? If so, what line raises the error and what is the error message?

Comment: @DavidZemens When I run the macro as written a new sheet is added but nothing is copied.  No errors occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your `j` loop:

```
For J = 0 To UBound(strArray)
```

The UpperBound (`Ubound`) of array `strArray` is 0. It's an array with a single element `"Aeronautic"`.

So your loop is looping once and exiting.

Instead try looping through your range:

```
For Each rngCell in rngCells.Cells
    if rngCell.value = "Aeronatic" Then 
        Found = True
        Exit For
    End if
Next rngCell
```

Here we loop through that `rngCells` range that you just made, cell by cell. Then we test if if the cell has the value you are looking for. If we find it, we set `found` to `true` and exit the for loop. You don't have to exit the for loop, but we found what we wanted, so there is no reason not to save some cpu time.

---

Full code, removed unnecessary variables and moved a little bit around:

```
Sub MoveAero()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim NoRows As Long
Dim DestNoRows As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Integer
Dim rngCells As Range
Dim rngCell as Range

Set wsSource = ActiveSheet

NoRows = wsSource.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
DestNoRows = 1
Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

For I = 1 To NoRows

    Set rngCells = wsSource.Range("AE" & I & ":BF" & I)

    For Each rngCell in rngCells.Cells
        if rngCell.value = "Aeronatic" Then 
            'Moved this logic up from the IF block below
            rngCells.EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Range("A" & DestNoRows)
            DestNoRows = DestNoRows + 1
            Exit For
        End if
    Next rngCell

Next I
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could use that `.find` method of the `range` object instead of the second `For` loop. (Using both for your needs is unnecessary).

```
Sub MoveAero()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim NoRows As Long
Dim DestNoRows As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim rngCells As Range

Set wsSource = ActiveSheet

NoRows = wsSource.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
DestNoRows = 1
Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

For I = 1 To NoRows

    Set rngCells = wsSource.Range("AE" & I & ":BF" & I)

    'Try to find your search term in the range
    If Not (rngCells.Find("Aeronautic") Is Nothing) Then
        rngCells.EntireRow.Copy wsDest.Range("A" & DestNoRows)
        DestNoRows = DestNoRows + 1
    End If

Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Replaced everything following  "For J" with what you selected and I'm now getting a for without next error.  I'd appreciate it if you could repost the full corrected code.  I seem to be screwing up trying to paste in your suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much @JNevill.  Greatly appreciate it

Comment: Not a problem. I have posted two version. I believe the second one will be quicker since it's using `find()` on the row/range instead of looping through every cell.

Comment: I have tried both versions just as you've written them and the macro still results in a blank worksheet without the desired copied rows.  I am not sure why.  Certainly I am doing something incorrect, but I felt it worthwhile telling you.  I will experiment and hopefully find a solution.

Again, thanks so much for you assistance

Comment: Make sure that your sheet that you are copying from is "Active" when you run this since you have `=activeSheet` in there. Make sure that `Aeronautic` is spelled the way that it appears in the sheet. Also, is `Aeronautic` the only thing in the cell, or does it appear with other text?

Comment: The sheet I'm working in is the only sheet in the workbook, so I assume it is "Active."  

I ran the macros with "Aeronautic" alone and also with a variation of one of the possible texts that would appear next to it in the cell "Aeronautic Engineers."  Both variations returned nothing even though there are numerous instances of cells with "Aeronautic Engineers" in the range.

Comment: Next thing is to understand if your `For` loop is actually looking at rows. Do you have data in column `A` of your worksheet? If not then your loop isn't looping since it's determining which rows to loop on based on that column. Change to `NoRows = wsSource.Range("AE65536").End(xlUp).Row` and see if that helps.

Comment: Woohoo!  That fixed it.  Thanks so much!  A did have data but there were some blank columns between A and AE.  Wish this site had a way to send a virtual beer coupon, I'd totally buy you one for this.  THANKS!! :)

Comment: LOL. I get fake internet points and the knowledge that I was able to help someone with a frustrating problem... so we're all good.